# URL is not exist on webapps folder

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Just finished setup Apache Tomcat 7 + MSSQL 2008 R2 + downloaded .war file + .bak file from someone's tutorial on internet for learn Java things, I successfuly get the web application and db connection works. What I have not implemented yet is install IDE (Eclipse? STS?) for editing purpose (should I?). For now I just simply use Sublime Text and stop/start tomcat to apply changes.

Check around little bit on the codes, then I stuck on this code in
/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/statistics.jsp

```
<a href="javascript:fn_excelDownLoad()"><img src="<c:url value="/res/img/btn_excel.gif"/>"/></a>
```

with the function described here:

```
function fn_excelDownLoad() {
    var totalRecordCount = "<c:out value='${paginationInfo.totalRecordCount}'/>";
    if(totalRecordCount > 65536){
        alert("Data is too big!!. Current Results is "+totalRecordCount+" rows. Please setting the DATE.");
        return;
    }
    var frm = document.searchForm;
    frm.action = '<c:url value="/admin/excelDownLoad"/>';
    frm.submit();
}
```

I need to re-format name of the downloaded excel file, but I have no found any **file with name excelDownload.jsp** in /WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ folder or even on entirely tomcat's /webapps/projectname/ folder!. I believe it relate with libraries or classes or something. ThankYou!

Comment: Have you looked in your application's web.xml file? Maybe it's not a jsp page, it's a servlet mapped to that url

Comment: @RubioRic Yeap. But found nothing related.

Comment: Use STS now and I found this code `<mime-mapping>
        <extension>xls</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I just figured out that the `.war` file is did not come with the source folder **(src/main/java folder)** which is contain `.java` files.